# what is the default AES config in crypto-js?

Tags: javascript, encryption, aes, cryptojs

https://cryptojs.gitbook.io/docs/ just said "CryptoJS supports AES-128, AES-192, and AES-256. It will pick the variant by the size of the key you pass in. If you use a passphrase, then it will generate a 256-bit key."

But what is default config like **mode**, **padding**, **iv** ? I notice there is a CipherOption for mode & padding

```
interface CipherHelper {
    encrypt(message: WordArray | string, key: WordArray | string, cfg?: CipherOption): CipherParams;
    decrypt(ciphertext: CipherParams | string, key: WordArray | string, cfg?: CipherOption): WordArray;
}
```

But I can't figure what the default value, e.g. it does not look like ECB mode by default.

My second question is how does it decide to use ace-128, aes-192, ase-256 based on the key I input, e.g. if I use a short string key like "my password" will it decide to use ace-128 then ? How ?

--- update ---

Except for the answer, I find [cryptojs: How to generate AES passphrase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22875419/cryptojs-how-to-generate-aes-passphrase) is also helpful to understand the passphrase used in CryptoJS.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your link to the CryptoJs-docs (https://cryptojs.gitbook.io/docs/) reveals the answers to your questions but we do have two scenarios.

1. you are feeding the encrypt function with a passphrase or 2) you are giving an explicit key as input.

**Scenario 1**: you feed a password/passphrase like "myPassword" to the function:

```
CryptoJS.AES.encrypt("Message", "Secret Passphrase");
```

Now CryptoJs **derives** a 32 byte long encryption key for AES-256 **and** a 16 byte long initialization vector (iv) from the password, encrypts the "Message" using this key, iv in AES mode **CBC** and (default) padding **Pkcs7**.

**Scenario 2**: you feed a key to the function:

```
var key = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse("000102030405060708090a0b0c0d0e0f");
​var iv = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse("101112131415161718191a1b1c1d1e1f");
​var encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt("Message", key, { iv: iv });
```

Now CryptoJs **takes** the key for AES-128/192/256 depending on the key length (16/24/32 bytes) **and** the 16 byte long initialization vector (iv) from the password, encrypts the "Message" using this key, iv in AES mode **CBC** and (default) padding **Pkcs7**.

**more options**: You can use other modes or padding when using the options like this (key + iv derivation from passphrase, AES mode CFB and padding AnsiX923):

```
var encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt("Message", "Secret Passphrase", {
  mode: CryptoJS.mode.CFB,
  padding: CryptoJS.pad.AnsiX923
});
```

Comment: Wow with your explanation I immediately understand what CryptoJs does when I pass in a string as the 2nd parameter. Thanks!

Comment: Hi can you check my another question about CryptoJS ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64786678/javascript-equivalent-to-java-sha1prng